# Unity is reusing my DbContext instead of creating a new instance each time

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, breeze

I am trying to use Unity as a resolver for creating my Breeze Web API controllers. Using breakpoints, it seems that the constructor for my AHSEFContextProvider is only being called one time.  Breeze requires a new instance each time otherwise the SaveChanges() method doesn't work properly.  I'm new to Unity but I thought using the TransientLifetimeManager (which I believe is the default anyway) would cause a new instance to be created each time.  Below is the UnityConfig code which is being called from the Global.asax Application_Start.  Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<AHSEFContextProvider<TaskDbContext>>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("ConnectionStringName"));
container.RegisterType<TaskController>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<AHSEFContextProvider<TaskDbContext>>()));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

Comment: I think that you probably want to use the `PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager ` for an EF Context. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx .  See the following SO post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187562/mvc-ef-datacontext-singleton-instance-per-web-request-in-unity

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it didn't make any difference changing from the TransientLifetimeManager to the PerResolveLifetimeManager.

Comment: Umm.. That's kind of the desired behavior (or at least should be). You *don't* want multiple instances of your context floating around, even if for some reason you *think* you do. You're going to run into all kinds of issues. There should be one instance of your context per request. Anything more than that is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work properly by adding the [InjectionConstructor] attribute to the constructor on my Breeze controller.  Then changing my Unity configuration as follows:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<AHSEFContextProvider<TaskDbContext>>(new InjectionConstructor("ConnectionStringName"));
container.RegisterType<AHS.Apps.Task.Server.BreezeControllers.TaskController>();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

Comment: Good job figuring that out