# New ApplicationDbContext() vs HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm a little confused about which way is better and which one to use. Surely if you can always get **HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get()**; then why even create a new **ApplicationDbContext** and risk doubling objects etc.?

Note: I'm specifically talking about a Web application here.

Comment: See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/02/07/entity-framework-context-lifetime-best-practices/

Comment: So "use the context per request" means that at least in Web Applications I should always be using HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();?

Comment: Generally, yes. Unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: Do you have an example of what would be a good reason not to?

Comment: As far as I know, you shouldn't be using the same instance of DbContext that you're using for Identity Framework within your application.  It is purely for use by Identity Framework... you should be generating a DbContext by other means outside of your Identity Framework methods (IE. Injecting it in using your IoC Container).

Comment: Also, although you *can* get a reference to the context using the above approach, a better way would be to *inject* the context instance instead of requesting it in a 'Service Locator' mode. Internally, your IoC container would return the same instance for the same request. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5191797

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DbContext instance that you create and can be retrieved using `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();` within your MVC application can be left exclusively for the use of Identity Framework.

If you need an instance of your DbContext for general use within your application, you can make use of an IoC Container (dependency injection) to provide you with a fresh instance of it as an when required and in request scope if desired.

You shouldn't *need* to retrieve the identity framework instance of the DbContext for the use within your application, it will be managed independently of your application and you can manage your own lifecycle.

Because you wired these up within the Owin Startup class to use an instance of your DbContext, they will make use of it under the hood and will create and destroy instances as and when it is required.

Comment: but sometimes i need to create a user and insert his ID into some tables in one transaction, otherwise i lose data integrity. What to do?

Comment: why Request.GetOwinContext().Get<MyDbContext>(); even exists then?

Comment: If you need to do something special during the login process, you should create a custom implementation of IUserStore and attach it to your identity setup. As for using the DbContext that identity uses, you should be creating and managing the life cycle of your DbContext yourself as with any application, this way it's creation and destruction is predictable.  You don't want the identity DbContext to be disposed before you need to use it. I hope this helps.

Comment: are you sure??  "The solution is to store a single instance of UserManager and DbContext per request and reuse them throughout the application. Since Identity hooks into the OWIN pipeline via cookie middleware, we can store the UserManager and DbContext in the OWIN context object and retrieve them as needed."

Comment: and "Also in the application if we need to work with the DbContext object directly we can get the instance of the class from the OWIN context as mentioned earlier using the ‘Get<T>’ method" https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity/

Comment: What did you end up doing in the end?

Comment: var db = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Get<YourDbContext>();

Comment: Cool.  Is that how you resolve it in your IoC container?

Comment: Downvoters - Please read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35616444/894792) for more discussion about this.  It isn't *wrong* to have one per request, nor is it *wrong* to create your DbContext per logical piece of work during the request, both are acceptable.  This answer enables both. Having control over your own DbContext instances isn't a bad thing. Maybe I went in a bit strong saying _the DbContext is just for identity framework_... updated.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution is to store a single instance of UserManager and DbContext per request and reuse them throughout the application. Since Identity hooks into the OWIN pipeline via cookie middleware, we can store the UserManager and DbContext in the OWIN context object and retrieve them as needed
>
> Also in the application if we need to work with the DbContext object directly we can get the instance of the class from the OWIN context as mentioned earlier using the ‘Get’ method

```
var dbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity/

Comment: I think I'd rather stick to having them separated out.  DbContext is a [lightweight object](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/359672/114058) after all.  It's not __wrong__ to have more than one created in a single request.  Two DbContexts used one after another in a request isn't a big deal.  It also means that you can allow your IoC container to intelligently create/destroy it per request.