# Dispose for Unit Of Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I have a code where controller calls service and service use Unit Of Work to handle DB. I have used Unity as dependency injection. I need to dispose unity(dbContext) automatically after request scope ends. I am not getting reference to PerRequestLifetimeManager in UnityCofig.cs. Any pointers?

Comment: Are you trying to find the PerRequestLifetimeManager, or do you ask for suggestion on how to dispose your UoW?

Comment: Doesn't unity detect if your UoW is disposable and automatically call Dispose when the request is finished?

Answer (score -1):

Try creating new derived type of lifetime manager

```
public class PerHttpRequestLifetime : LifetimeManager
{
    // This is very important part and the reason why I believe mentioned
    // PerCallContext implementation is wrong.
    private readonly Guid _key = Guid.NewGuid();

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Items[_key];
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[_key] = newValue;
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        var obj = GetValue();
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(obj);
    }
}
```

Source: 
[MVC, EF - DataContext singleton instance Per-Web-Request in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187562/mvc-ef-datacontext-singleton-instance-per-web-request-in-unity)

Comment: Will this automatically call Dispose on DBContext on call of RemoveValue()?

Comment: Accidentally voted down. Could you please edit the answer so that I can remove it?