# Some of the Navigation properties are lost while result is transferred from WCF service to MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework

This issue is becoming a nightmare for me, especially, after days of research there is nothing in favor.
The problem is that, some of the navigation properties are lost.
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380495/navigation-properties-are-showing-null-randomly) for code details
I am using Entity framework with repository pattern, and also have tried out setting "SetMergeOption" to "NoMerge" for Objectset but this didnt help either

Comment: I got them working after updating POCO generator to use EF version 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got them working after updating POCO generator to use EF version 5.0